# rekindling the American right’s love -- what does that mean?

Tags: comprehension

Source: [Obama again gets the last laugh against Putin](http://www.msnbc.com/rachel-maddow-show/obama-again-gets-the-last-laugh-against-putin)

Example:

> That is, until a few months ago, when the Russian president deployed forces to Syria, **rekindling the American right’s love**. Republican White House hopefuls once again praised Putin’s bold “leadership,” as did like-minded pundits. The Washington Post’s Jennifer Rubin argued, “In taking this action just days after meeting with President Obama, Putin is delivering one more finger in the eye of a president whom he continues to out-wit and out-muscle.”

I don't understand what they're talking about.

Comment: Bringing back the love that was off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> That is, until a few months ago, when the Russian president deployed forces to Syria, rekindling the American **right**’s love.

By his actions in Syria Putin revived the feeling of affection towards him among the **[right-wing politicians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-wing_politics)** of the USA.

"American right" means American parties, movements and politicians on the right side of the political spectrum.

Comment: Aha, that's what they're talking about--right wingers.

Comment: Да. Он "вернул себе любовь Американских *правых* политиков". (Yes. He brought back the love of US-based *right* politicians).

Answer (score 1):

To put it in simple words: *bringing back the love that was off*.

The word *rekindle* is often used with *fire*, that is, to set it again, which adapted to the context, it's to put back their love.